# Multiple wordpress installs working from a single database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a use case for multiple wordpress installs across different domains which have access to a single database, so posts, pages and so on are shared between the two. Each install however needs separate settings.

The reason being is that one install will act as a secure admin panel which is IP whitelisted and available only over https with read and write access, whilst the second will sit on the client facing server, and have only read access to the database.

I have tried changing the prefix within wp-config.php,

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_'; //install one
```

-

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp2_'; //install two
```

but this of course created a second version of all tables. Is there a correct solution to this? or will I need to write custom SQL, removing the need for the second wordpress install?

Comment: This probably won't work because wordpress will complain about site_url and home_url being different. You could try to use mysql replication and a read only db account for the client facing site. I can't say that would work 100% though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try network enabled WordPress(WordPRess Multisite). otherwise, you don't have choice, you need to create the tables once again to work on the same database.  if you looking network enable in wordpress try this code page.

[Read Here in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: ended up creating a second options table and running each install with separate options, but keeping all other tables the same.